# one ajax function runs on same form for multiple rows

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an ajax function that populating multiple fields based on item selected. But I would like to have extra rows that people may select more items in the same form. And trying to have the same ajax function running in rest of the rows instead of just one. Some of the rows might leave blank after form submitted.

What is the best way to populate the multiple fields in multiple rows based on the code I have?

Here is my code for form and it now only has one row for users to select and insert but I would like to have about 10 rows for users:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="placedOrder.php">
    <table width="70%" border="5" align="center">
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Item Name</th>
            <th scope="row">Item SKU</th>
            <th scope="row">Quantity</th>
            <th scope="row">Side Mark</th>
            <th scope="row">Unit Price</th>
            <th scope="row">Total Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">
                <?php
                    include('connect.php');

                    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT description FROM products") 
                            or die(mysqli_error());
                    print '<select name="description" id="description" value="description">';
                    print '<option value="" disabled selected>Please Select A Product</option>';
                    while ($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        $p = $info["description"];
                        $p = htmlspecialchars($p);
                        printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $p, $p);
                    }
                    print '</select>';
                    ?>
            </th>
            <th scope="row">
                <input name="sku_1" id="sku_1" readonly />
            </th>
            <th scope="row">
                <input name="qty_1" />
            </th>
            <th scope="row">
                <input name="note_1" />
            </th>
            <th scope="row">
                <input name="uPrice_1" id="uPrice_1" readonly />
            </th>
            <th scope="row">
                <input name="tPrice_1" id="tPrice_1" readonly />
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

For here is my ajax function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#description').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'orderAuto.php',
            data: {
                description: $('#description').val()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) //on recieve of reply
            {
                var skuId = data[0]; 
                var unitPrice = data[1];
                $('#sku_1').val(skuId);
                $('#uPrice_1').val(unitPrice);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
    include('connect.php');
    $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT sku_id, unit_price FROM products WHERE description= '".$p."'");
    $array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your AJAX method as a named function that takes an array of selectors: that will allow you to reuse that function and add more event handlers that utilize it.

Something like:

```
function myAJAX(selectorArray) {
    $.ajax({
        //bunch of stuff
       data: { description: $(this).val() },
       // more stuff
       success: function(data){
         var skuId = data[0], 
             unitPrice = data[1];
         selectorArray[0].val(skuId);
         selectorArray[1].val(unitPrice);
       }
    });
}
```

Another way would be to use a class selector for your event handler and specifying a target element within it.

```
$('mySelector').on('change', '#targetSelector', myAJAX(selectors));
```

The idea here is to use a parent selector and an additional selector within it.

```
<div id="box"> 
    <p id="text">Here is some text.</p>
    <p>This is also some text</p>
</div>
```

In this example HTML we have a `div` as the parent and some `p`'s as the children. So if we wanted to use our event handler (assuming we don't need any additional arguments) it would look like this:

```
$('#box').on('change', '#text', myAJAX);
```

We are selecting the parent of the element we want to change asyncronously and filtering to the specific element we want to change with our AJAX call. For more information, see the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for using the `on` method to handle events.

Comment: hmmm looks like by using class selector is much easier. I'm new with ajax function. Can you explain little more detail if possible? really appreciate for your help!

Comment: Hopefully that is what you were looking for,.